# Same code but different result with Xcode 3.2.6 and Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, search, header

Compiling with Xcode 3.26 and SDK 4.3 and I had a table with a search field and below that a section header which came into view after a search. To indicate it was a search table. The header was green and just said "Result". If not searching it was invisible.

Now compiling the same code with Xcode 4.1.1 and SDK 5.1 the header works the same way after a search but is always visible even when not searching. Turns grey and is floating on top of the table all the time below the navigation bar.

What can I do about it? Prefer the way it was before.

The code is like this.

```
    -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:    (NSInteger)section{if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{   UILabel *tempHeaderLabel=[[UILabel  alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,30)];
    tempHeaderLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:67.0/255.0 green:126.0/255.0 blue:71.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    tempHeaderLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:227.0/255.0 green:227.0/255.0 blue:227.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    tempHeaderLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-BoldItalic" size:16];
    tempHeaderLabel.text=@"                          Result";


    return tempHeaderLabel;
}
else

    return nil;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried testing on a device? There is a display bug with the 4.3 Sim when running with Xcode 4.

Comment: No I have not so far. Will do it shortly. I was wrong in the question. I compiled it with Xcode 4.4.1 and is using 5.1 sim.